# Android layout sw600dp not woking

Tags: android, layout

I have problem with layout `sw600dp`. I have two folder `layout` and `layout-sw600dp`. Everything was allright since today. Tablets and phones use right folder with layotus but i had to change my version of app, and it broked. Now my app only use version for phones. I test it on few device -> tablet 7" and tablet 10".

I have tried change for sw500dp but it didnt help.

Have you any idea what is wrong?

PS: I saw a lot of posts and documentation about it and can't find answer for my issue

Comment: what do you mean changing the version of your app?

Comment: go to build.gradle and change versionName from 1.2.7 to 1.2.8

Comment: Its look like my app ignore folder layout-sw600dp -> when i delete file from layout app going to crash

Comment: try to clean and build your project

Comment: i tried it for many times. nothing changed

Comment: OK i was my fault i made mistake in targetSdkVersion :) ty for answer :)